# Adding AngularJs to a Bootstrap Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a certain Bootstrap Theme purchased from ThemeForest for building  a Web Application Project.

To be specific the theme referred to is - http://themeforest.net/item/modern-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/11004840

I have already completed the Frontend using that theme. Now when I start adding in the backend and integrating, I feel it might be more effective to use AngularJS than use Jquery to manipulate the DOM and the objects.

Can I just start using AngularJS for the dom manipulations in the same project? Or will I be facing any problems? I would like to check if there will be any conflicts arising out of me using both together ?

If there are any tutorials, please refer that to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular and bootstrap are 100% compatible. Just add the script tag for angular into your bootstrap project and you have a hybrid angular bootstrap project.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just tried doing that. Works well it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You will have no problems at all. If you're looking for examples of open source AngularJS projects which used Bootstrap, there are multitudes. Here's one of my own over on Github: https://github.com/JohnMunsch/PaperQuik

Note: In addition to being able to just use the two together, there's also projects like [Angular Strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) which provide Angular directives to wrap the various components (both JavaScript and not) provided by Bootstrap and make it easier to integrate them into your AngularJS code.